# Index file being returned for all requests

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angularjs

I'm relatively new to web development. I'm using node (with express) and angular JS. While the solution may be simple, I can't determine why the contents of every requested file (css/javascript/html) is being returned with the contents of my index.html file.

The following screenshot from the chrome inspector illustrates the issue:

What is being displayed for the contents of the controller.js file is actually the contents of the index.html file.

[image]

You can see the relevant contents from the index file in the screen shot. The following is the node server code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    api = require('./routes/api');

var app = module.exports = express();

// Configuration
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

// JSON API
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);

// Start server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

The routes.js file (in routes directory):

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

//get correct directory path
var filePath = __dirname.replace('routes', 'views/')

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(filePath + 'index.html');
};

exports.partials = function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.sendfile(filePath + 'partials/' + name + '.html');
};
```

It seems that every request for a resource is returning with the contents of index (including image files). Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

You want to move that before the other `app.get()`'s. Basically you've told the server to respond to every request with `index.html` after setting up a bunch of other routes.

Comment: Hey Jason, moving this catchall line to the top of the 'get's didn't seem to have any effect- the index file is still being returned. Taking that line out entirely results in 404s rather than 200s though. Would that mean I need to set up routes specifically for the js/cs files?

Comment: It definitely means your files are not in the right place... You shouldn't have to setup a route for each one though. Do you have a public directory inside your public directory otherwise the public in the path in index.html is superfluous?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Jason- it was a matter of having the files in the right place (there is no public directory inside of the public directory).